# How to use onSlideAfter() event for bxSlider loaded with option useCSS set true?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bxslider

I'd like to load bxSlider (http://bxslider.com) with the useCSS option set true to avoid using jQuery transitions. However, this would impede the script from triggering the onSlideAfter() event.

This is what my sliderConfig looks like:

```
slider_config = {
    infiniteLoop: false,
    slideWidth: 400,
    pager: false,
    swipeThreshold: 30,
    slideMargin: 0,
    startSlide: 0,
    hideControlOnEnd: true,
    useCSS: true,
    onSliderLoad: function() {  
        console.log('onSliderLoad'); //executed
    },
    onSlideAfter: function($slideElement) {
        console.log('onSlideAfter'); //not executed if useCSS: true
    },
    onSlideBefore: function($slideElement, oldIndex, newIndex) {
        console.log('onSlideBefore'); //executed
    },
    onSlideNext: function($slideElement, oldIndex, newIndex) {
        console.log('onSlideNext'); //executed
    }

};

slider = $('#mydiv').bxSlider(slider_config);
```

Any hints appreciated - in the meantime, I'm gonna remove the useCSS option.

Answer (score 1):

The only reason I can see is that there's no oldIndex and newIndex as parameters like you have at onSlideBefore().
I have a bxslider with useCSS as true, and it's all working, so that might be issue.

```
 onSlideAfter: function($slideElement, oldIndex, newIndex) {
        console.log('onSlideAfter');
 }
```